# Where is the identifier in the attributes inspector for a table view?

Tags: ios

In this table view tutorial http://www.colejoplin.com/2012/09/28/ios-tutorial-basics-of-table-views-and-prototype-cells-in-storyboards/ it says to set the identifier within the attributes inspector, however I have no identifier field appearing for my table view.

[image]

As a separate question, why is both an identifier and a tag needed to identify cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tap on Cell in storyboard and you can see this:

[image]

my cell for example is called cellTN...

Answer (score 0):

In answer to you're separate question:

> As a separate question, why is both an identifier and a tag needed to
>   identify cells?

You do not need to identify anything with a tag. 
An example of using a tag would be when searching through the subviews of a UIView and needing to find a specific view. If you have tagged the view with a number (say 44), you can search like this:

```
UIView *specificSubview;
for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    if (subview.tag == 44)
        specificSubview = subview;
if (!specificSubview)   return;
else
{
    // do something with subview
}
```